# Mend a Silicone lump

Tags: bathroom, silicone

Last night I made a vertical silicone bead Roughly 1.8m long. I used a fugi tool.  The bead has a 10cm section that looks lumpy in the Centre. Now it has been curing for 12hours. Can I cut this section out a reapply a layer?.

Comment: Wow someone is actually making money selling a tool that does the same thing I have been using my finger to do all these years. <eyeroll>

Answer (score 1):

The stuff cures at about 1mm per day. Wait until it has cured all the way through before cutting into it.